# How to Copy/upload the csv file to a google spread sheet using python scripting

Tags: python

How to Copy/upload the csv file to a google spread sheet using python scripting .Please share with some examples

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pprint

import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient import discovery

from googleapiclient import discovery


try:
    import argparse
flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args() except ImportError:flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'



def get_credentials():
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):os.makedirs(credential_dir)
credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

  store = Storage(credential_path)
  credentials = store.get()
  if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
     flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
     flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
     if flags:
         credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
     else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
         credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
     print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
   return credentials
```

credentials = get_credentials()

```
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

discoveryUrl =    ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?''version=v4')

print (credentials)

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

```
spreadsheet_id = '1oH2nTJblDvcIVySuBzIXJF-Np3xsCBkCqTDkg9TCBrc'  
range_ = 'Sheet1!A1:B4'
```

value_input_option = 'RAW'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

```
insert_data_option = 'INSERT_ROWS'  



f= open('/home/vinaykn/Documents/test2.csv')
data= f.read()
f.close()

get_data = data

 print (get_data)

 value_range_body = {
    "values":  
  ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
  ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
  ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
  ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"]
 }

 request =        service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,   range=range_, valueInputOption=value_input_option,   insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
response = request.execute()

 pprint(response)
```

Comment: [This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive) is what I use at work. Make some code attempts.

Comment: Hi since i am new to python searching for the same.Currently i have attempted to write in the google sheet.But i need to copy /upload the csv file data to google spread sheet.

Comment: [Follow the steps](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html) you will need to set up your OAuth access first, just follow the instructions.

Comment: I have all created those steps,and stuck only in uploading/copying to spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many survey i have found an answer.

http://wescpy.blogspot.in/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html

This should be able to do for uploading or downloading